# Ubuntu after boot shows a black screen with a warning reboot required

Tags: wubi

I installed ubuntu in my system already having windows xp using wubi.. 
After the rebooting i selected ubuntu and a black screen appears with a message stack : 49 59 aa and stops thr and does not boot it is also telling it has changed to text console due to error and it hangs.... my keyboard does not work after that.

what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall your Ubuntu through Ubiquity (LiveCD, DVD and USB standard Ubuntu installer) because Wubi file system isn't normal for Ubuntu.

Comment: I doubt wubi has anything to do with the problem. Does the live (desktop) cd boot ? If not, can you post the exact error message.

Comment: Please, write me the partition table on your desktop.

Comment: Yes, you must if you want install Ubuntu normally.

Comment: thanks for the reply.... the exact error that is showing is that "fault is corrected but reboot is necessary" and when i reboot also its showing the same error.... my partition is in C drive-windows xp D drive -software setups E- movies , F- i installed wubi and ubuntu folder is thr...Sorry for the late reply... Thanks a lot.... Pls do help